# Ruby OpenSSL DES encoding "wrong final block length"

Tags: ruby, encoding, openssl

I have the following encryption/decryption using OpenSSL (under Linux in my example):

```
$ echo test | openssl des -a -K 79616d7379616d73 -iv 1234567890ABCDEF
+ax5NT+Pjh0=

$ echo +ax5NT+Pjh0= | openssl des -a -d -K 79616d7379616d73 -iv 1234567890ABCDEF
test
```

All good. I need to translate it in Ruby code. As far as I did:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'openssl'

key = "\x79\x61\x6d\x73\x79\x61\x6d\x73"
iv = "\x12\x34\x56\x78\x90\xAB\xCD\xEF"
todecode = "+ax5NT+Pjh0="

def decode(encryptedString, key, iv)
    decrypt = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new('des-cbc')
    decrypt.decrypt
    decrypt.key = key
    decrypt.iv = iv
    decrypt.update(encryptedString) + decrypt.final
end

decoded = decode(todecode, key, iv)

puts decoded
```

It throws me the following error:

```
decode.rb:14:in `final': wrong final block length (OpenSSL::Cipher::CipherError)`
```

What am I doing wrong? Did I select the wrong encryption or wrong use of key/iv?

Comment: Small nit... Use `echo  -n`, not `echo` (unless you want the new line). But it probably is not the cause of your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems I forgot to base64_decode the string.

`todecode = Base64::decode64("+ax5NT+Pjh0=")`